# Google site-related links

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I have a website I'm currently working with, I was wondering about the default behaviour of search. Currently, to show a subset of links related to the page under the same search result, I have to use the exact name of the site. Is there a way to always display these through SEO or is this just default google behaviour?

Notice that when the non-exact site name is used, the links still appear just without their descriptions. The below screenshots are taken from chrome without cache or cookies (incognito)

[image: Non-Exact Site Name]

[image: Exact Site Name]

Comment: The only way to get the bigger sitelinks is to have your site rank *so highly* for a query that Google decides you deserve all that real estate. There's no shortcut. See this question for more details: